# How to speed up the processing time of long article with StanfordCoreNLP (v3.9.2)

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have an article with 8226 chars, what i want is extracting NERs. (check the original article at [Here](https://www.rediff.com/news/special/parrikar-tamed-death-and-lived-like-a-warrior-king/20190319.htm))

Using command as below cost **8.0 sec** at NERCombinerAnnotator

```
 java -cp "./*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -ner.nthreads 4 -file longArticleSample.txt -outputFormat json
```

[image]

Also, I have tried another article with 1973 chars in the same way. It takes **4.2 sec** to get NERs.

```
java -cp "./*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -ner.nthreads 4 -file mediumArticle.txt -outputFormat json
```

[image]

This result is much less efficient than the author's result.(both use Token+SS+PoS+L+NER)

**[My Result]**

- MediumLengthArticle: 4.5 sec. for 356 tokens at **78.4 tokens/sec**.
- LongArticle: 8.4 sec. for 1683 tokens at **200.3 tokens/sec**.

**[Stanford Result]**

- More than **10,000 tokens/sec**.
- [originalSite](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/memory-time.html#parse)
- [image: List item]

Comment: And, I have tried use different ```n.threads``` params, but the time didn't change much. Seems somehow the params is not effective.

Comment: When I set ```-ner.applyFineGrained false```, it does reduce the time magically( 8 sec -> 0.2 sec). But, all the tokens' NER are "O", is there anything wrong? I'm using v3.9.2 from maven